# mixture of field:value and value initializers

Tags: go

Why can I not create the following, with an anonymous field?

```
type T1 struct {
    T1_Text string
}

type T2 struct {
    T2_Text string
    T1
}
```

used in func ..

```
t := T2{
    T2_Text: "Test",
    T1{T1_Text: "Test"},
}
```

Gives me: mixture of field:value and value initializers?

Comment: The syntax is just off: `T1: T1{...}`.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

A brief explanation.

The reason you get that is because you are allowed to only use one of the two types of initializers and not both.

i.e. you can either use **field:value** or **value.**

Using your example you either do

*field:value*

```
t := T2{
    T2_Text: "Test",
    T1: T1{T1_Text: "Test"},
}
```

*or only values*

```
t := T2{
    "Test",
    T1{"Test"},
}
```

Hope that explains the why

Answer (score 25):

Missing the attribute name `T1` for assignment.

```
t := T2{
    T2_Text: "Test",
    T1:      T1{T1_Text: "Test"},
}
```

P.S. Just moved @twotwotwo's comment to an answer.

Comment: I am facing similar issue, gettign an error -  prog.go:30:13: undefined: Principal package main

import (
 "fmt"
)

type Service string

type NameType struct {
    First string
    Last  string
    Principal Service
}

type UserType struct {
    NameType
    Username string
}




func main() {
 fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
 
 user := UserType{
    NameType: NameType{
        First: "Eduardo",
        Last:  "Nunes",
 Principal: Principal{
 Service: "Service name",
 }, 
    },
    Username: "esnunes",
}

fmt.Println("Hello, playground ", user)

}

Comment: However you can mix _named_ fields with _anonymous_ fields in a **struct**, as long as those _named_ fields are of type `interface{}`, [for example](https://go.dev/play/p/fUPwwv7uMkO)